# How to show and hide array in uitableview

Tags: ios, xcode, arrays, uitableview, hide

I tried to load my `Array`s like this, but it loads just first `Array` and others doesn't displayed.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[documentPaths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.plist"];

    NSDictionary *myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];



    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"blackKey"])
    {
        NSArray *black = [myDict objectForKey:@"Black"];
        self.tableData = [black copy];
    }
    else if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"greenKey"])
    {
        NSArray *green = [myDict objectForKey:@"Green"];
        self.tableData = [green copy];
    }
    else if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"purpleKey"])
    {
        NSArray *purple = [myDict objectForKey:@"Purple"];
        self.tableData = [purple copy];
    }
    else if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"orangeKey"])
    {
    NSArray *orange = [myDict objectForKey:@"Orange"];
        self.tableData = [orange copy];
    }
    else if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"blueKey"])
    {
        NSArray *blue = [myDict objectForKey:@"Blue"];
        self.tableData = [blue copy];
    }
    else if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"redKey"])
    {
        NSArray *red = [myDict objectForKey:@"Red"];
        self.tableData = [red copy];
    }
    else if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"darkblueKey"])
    {
        NSArray *darkblue = [myDict objectForKey:@"Darkblue"];
        self.tableData = [darkblue copy];
    }
    else if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"yellowKey"])
    {
        NSArray *yellow = [myDict objectForKey:@"Yellow"];
        self.tableData = [yellow copy];
    }


    }
```

1. What I doing wrong?
2. Also, I would like to show Arrays title as Section title, how it can
   be done?
3. And is there a way to limit rows per section (my Array)?

**EDIT**

```
// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [tableData count];
}



// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *dict = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", [dict objectForKey:@"Name"], [dict objectForKey:@"Address"]];

    return cell;
}
```

**EDIT2**

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    [sectionsTitle objectForKey:[sectionTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
}
```

Use of undeclared identifier 'indexPath'; did you mean 'NSIndexPath'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are going to divide them to sections, Your tableData should be `NSMutableDictionary`
And you will also need to hold an array of the keys for the dictionary
Like this

```
NSMutableDictionary *resultDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSDictionary *myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"blackKey"])
{
    NSArray *black = [myDict objectForKey:@"Black"];

    //Add the key here
    [resultArray addObject:@"Black"];
    //Add the key and value
    [resultDic setValue:black forKey:@"Black"];
}
else if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"greenKey"])
{
    NSArray *green = [myDict objectForKey:@"Green"];

    //Add the key here
    [resultArray addObject:@"Green"];
    //Add the key and value
    [resultDic setValue:black forKey:@"Green"];
}
//Repeat for all the elements
....
//Then after you finished all the tests and additions

//Assign the result array to your tableData
self.tableData = resultDic;
self.sectionsTitle = resultArray;
```

Now in use the `sectionsTitle` and `tableData` to fill your table
For any section in the table you can get its title from `[sectionsTitle objectAtIndex:sectionIndex];`
To get all the elements in a section use `[sectionsTitle objectForKey:[sectionTitle objectAtIndex:sectionIndex]];`

Comment: Thanks, seems it works! Can you help me with other questions? How can I set my Arrays (Black, Green) to Section title?

Comment: when I set tableData as NSMutableDictionary I got ARC issue "No visible @interface for 'NSMutableDictionary' declares the selector 'objectAtIndex:'"

Comment: In your cellForRow, you will need to change the following  NSDictionary *dict = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", [dict objectForKey:@"Name"], [dict objectForKey:@"Address"]]; to **NSDictionary *dict = [tableData objectForKey:[sectionTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
   cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", [dict objectForKey:@"Name"], [dict objectForKey:@"Address"]];**

Comment: Ok.. I got last issue.. Use of undeclared identifier 'sectionIndex' and 'sectionTitle'. I am very grateful for your help!

Comment: it was a pleasure :), please dont forget to accept the answer if it was useful :)

Comment: how can I declare identifiers 'sectionIndex' and 'sectionTitle'?

Comment: in your example **sectionIndex** would be **indexPath.section** and sectionsTitle add a new property of type NSMutableArray to your .h file, in your .m file @synthesize it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12575/discussion-between-omar-abdelhafith-and-pavel-kaljunen)